# schengen mother and child hotel reservations

Tags: schengen

I am having trouble getting hotels to include child's name in hotel reservation. For Schengen visa purposes, is having the mother's name sufficient on hotel reservations?

Answer (score 1):

Normally yes. The hotel booking should be in your name. And because you child is a dependent, it will not be a problem. However make sure the hotel booking shows that the stay includes also a child.

Comment: "The hotel booking shows that the stay includes also a child" <- how exactly do you propose they do this?  You can't really do more than ensure there's enough beds.

Comment: When you book the hotel and include a child, the booking shows that a child is booked. Irrespective of beds. Just like when you book flights

Comment: For example, I just looked up one of my hotel reservations. It has the following line: "Number of Guests:  Adults: 1 Children: 0".